# No module named 'requests' when running python executable, even it's installed

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, modulenotfounderror

i have a problem with running my python.exe file, because it says that there is no requests module, but when i run pip list it's installed. No idea why it happens (i am working on VM with windows if that changes something). Already tried uninstalling the package and reinstalling it with both pip and pip3, no changes. Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Full error callback?

Comment: Check `pip --version` to see if your `pip` operates on the your interpreter. Also consider using `python -m pip …`.

Comment: Not really sure, as i tried to install the module in cmd from Python38/Scripts folder and it seemed to work.

Comment: `python -m pip install requests` can sometimes do the trick (assuming you're running Python via some command line).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the methods listed below for **Windows**:-

1. Open CMD Prompt and use this:-

> Path\easy_install.exe requests

and replace **Path** with your **Python*\Scripts** folder,.
It will be like this:-

> C:\Python32\Scripts)

2. The second option is download a compressed library and put it in the Lib\site-packages folder of your python path after uncompressing it.
   It will be like this:-

> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages)

After downloading just run `python setup.py install` from **cmd**.

You can find missing libraries [here](https://pypi.org/). To download requests click [here](https://pypi.org/project/requests/).